# How to get single value from array made from the range function

Tags: php, arrays

It's been a late night so this I know is a pretty easy question. I have the following code:

```
$letters = range('A', 'Z');
$inx = 0;
$unique = false;
$num = substr($vin,-6);
while($unique != true){
    if($inx > 0){
        $num = substr($vin,-6) + $letters[$inx];
    }
    $this->db->where('stockid', $num);
    $query = $this->db->get('vehicles');
    if($query->num_rows() < 1){
        $unique = true;
    }
    $inx++;
}
```

I get an error because it is not pulling a letter and adding it to the string where it states:

```
$num = substr($vin,-6) + $letters[$inx];
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? More importantly, what exactly are you trying to do here? This code looks like you may be better off getting a good nights sleep in before writing any more.

Comment: You most likely want to use `.` instead of `+` as I assume you try to concatenate strings/characters.

Comment: You need a very good reason to put query inside a php-cycle. Do you really have one?

Comment: I wish I could sleep but senior project is due tm :-/ I used the . and it did not make a difference. I am getting the following error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Then your query fails and your error handling is broken, I'd say. :) It has nothing to do with the line you point out.

Comment: It's clearly not able to pull the letter out of the array even though $inx is numeric.

Comment: I figured it out. It ended up being the dumb plus sign. Sleep deprived at it's best. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this instead:

```
$num.=$letters[$inx];
```

versus

```
$num = substr($vin,-6) + $letters[$inx];
```

Because we often use "+" in Javascript.